# Problemas para hacer upload un archivo con otros parametros, enviandolos por ajax a un servlet

Tags: java, ajax, upload

Necesito enviar un formulario que tiene dos input=file y otros parametros, los estoy enviando mediante ajax a un servlet que recibe un parametro URL que lo uso para determinar la funcion específica para ese proceso (un servlet para todo mi modulo)... He estado investigando pero no funciona, voy a colocar los codigos para que me ayuden a indentificar que es lo que ocurre.

EL **HTML**

```
<form id="frmEstMdo" name="frmEstMdo" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="validation-message">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2" for="inputDefault">Tipo Objeto <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <select class="form-control custom-select" name="tipo_bien" id="tipo_bien" title="Seleccione el Tipo Objeto." required>                                                             
                <option value="B">BIEN</option>
                <option value="S">SERVICIO</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label text-lg-right pt-2" for="inputDefault">Año <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ano_eje" name="ano_eje" title="Ingrese Año Ejecucion." min="2010" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2">Subir Documento <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="url_documento" name="url_documento" class="file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" title="Debe seleccionar el TDR o las Especificaciones Tecnicas." required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2" for="textareaDefault">Concepto <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <textarea class="form-control UpperCase" rows="3" id="concepto" name="concepto" title="Ingrese Concepto del Estudio de Mercado." required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2">Subir Justificacion <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="url_justificacion" name="url_justificacion" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" title="Debe seleccionar la Justificacion del Pedido." required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2" for="inputDefault">Plazo hasta <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">                                                        
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" data-timepicker="true" data-time-format="hh:ii AA" id="tmp_plazo" name="tmp_plazo" class="datepicker-here form-control" data-language='es'>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                                                                                                                
        <label class="col-lg-1 control-label text-lg-right pt-2" for="inputDefault">Entregar en</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control UpperCase" id="lugar_entrega" name="lugar_entrega">  
        </div>    
    </div>

</div>
<footer class="card-footer">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCancelar">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**SCRIPTS**

```js
var $FormEstMdo= $("#frmEstMdo");
$FormEstMdo.validate({        
 errorContainer: $FormEstMdo.find( 'div.validation-message' ),
 errorLabelContainer: $FormEstMdo.find( 'div.validation-message ul' ),
 wrapper: "li", 
 submitHandler: function(form) {
  var plazo = moment($("#tmp_plazo").val(),"DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A");
  plazo = plazo.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  $.ajax({
   //enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   dataType: 'json',                
   processData: false,  // Important!
   //contentType: false,
   type: 'post',
   url: "./Adquisiciones?url=InsertEstMdo",
   async: true,
   data: $FormEstMdo.serialize() + "&plazo=" + plazo + ".000",
   beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
   },
   success: function (response) {
    console.log(response.msg);
      if(response.exito){
     var notice = new PNotify({
      title: 'Operacion exitosa',
      text: 'Ha registrado un nuevo Estudio de Mercado.',
      addclass: 'notification-primary click-2-close',
      icon: 'fa fa-info-circle',
      hide: true,
      buttons: {
        closer: false,
        sticker: false
      }
     });
      }else{
     var notice = new PNotify({
      title: 'Ha ocurrido un error',
      text: 'No se ha podido registrar el Estudio de Mercado. Error inesperado.',
      type: 'error',
      addclass: 'click-2-close',
      icon: 'fa fa-times-circle',
      hide: true,
      buttons: {
        closer: false,
        sticker: false
      }
     });
       
      }
    notice.get().click(function() {
     notice.remove();
    });                    
   }
   
  });
 }
});
```

**SERVLET** (He borrado algunas cosas que no vienen al caso, estoy intetando al menos leer el nombre del archivo pero esta saliendo un error.)

package gob.grsm.estudiomercado.servlet;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import static config.ConexionReporte.obtenerPropiedad;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.beans.Cotizaciones;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.beans.Dashboard;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.beans.EstudioMercado;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.beans.Requisitos;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.beans.SCEMContratistas;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.beans.SolicitudesCotizaciones;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.beans.tmp_SendCotizaProvee;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.dao.CotizacionesDao;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.dao.DashboardDao;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.dao.EstudioMercadoDao;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.dao.RequisitosDao;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.dao.SCEMContratistasDao;
import gob.grsm.estudiomercado.dao.SolicitudesCotizacionesDao;
import gob.grsm.maestrassiga.beans.SIGAContratistas;
import gob.grsm.maestrassiga.dao.SIGAContratistasDao;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 *
 * @author lescudero
 */
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2, // 2MB 
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10MB 
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50)
@WebServlet(name = "EstudioMercadoServlet", urlPatterns = {"/Adquisiciones"})

public class EstudioMercadoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    String pathFtp;

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("url") == null ? "" : request.getParameter("url");
    switch (action) {
        case "EstudioMercado":
            estudiomercado(request, response);
            break;
        case "PanelProveedor":
            mipanel(request, response);
            break;
        case "GetSearchSiga":
            getsearchsiga(request, response);
            break;
        case "GetContratistas":
            getcontratistas(request, response);
            break;
        case "GetRequisitos":
            getrequisitos(response);
            break;    
        case "InsertDataContratistas":
            insertdatacontratistas(request, response);
            break;     
        case "InsertEstMdo":
            insertestmdo(request, response);
            break;
        case "getEstsMdo":
            getestsmdo(request, response);
            break;              
        case "getCotizaProvee":
            getcotizaprovee(request, response);
            break;                
        case "PublicarANDSend":
            publicarandsend(request, response);
            break;
        case "GetSolicitudes":
            getlistasolicitudes(request, response);
            break;
        case "GetProveedor":
            getdatosprove(request, response);
            break; 
        case "GetDetalleEstMdo":
            getdetalleestmdo(request, response);
            break;  
    }
}


private void insertestmdo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    /*response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    long fechaHoy = System.currentTimeMillis();                        
    String ano_eje= request.getParameter("ano_eje");
    String tipo_bien = request.getParameter("tipo_bien");
    String nro_pedido = request.getParameter("nro_pedido");
    if(nro_pedido.equals("")){nro_pedido=null;}
    String nro_consolid = request.getParameter("nro_consolid");
    if(nro_consolid.equals("")){nro_consolid=null;}
    String nro_paac = request.getParameter("nro_paac");
    if(nro_paac.equals("")){nro_paac=null;}
    String nro_est_mdo = request.getParameter("nro_est_mdo");
    if(nro_est_mdo.equals("")){nro_est_mdo=null;}
    String concepto = request.getParameter("concepto");                
    String glosa_est_mdo = null;        
    java.sql.Timestamp fecha_pedido = (request.getParameter("fecha_pedido").equals(""))?null:java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(request.getParameter("fecha_pedido")); 
    java.sql.Timestamp fecha_reg_vb = (request.getParameter("fecha_reg_vb").equals(""))?null:java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(request.getParameter("fecha_reg_vb")); 
    java.sql.Timestamp fecha_paac = (request.getParameter("fecha_paac").equals(""))?null:java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(request.getParameter("fecha_paac"));
    java.sql.Timestamp fecha_mdo = (request.getParameter("fecha_mdo").equals(""))?null:java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(request.getParameter("fecha_mdo"));                                      
    String estado_est_mdo = "R";

    java.sql.Timestamp plazo = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(request.getParameter("plazo"));        
    String url_documento = request.getParameter("url_documento");
    String url_justificacion = request.getParameter("url_justificacion");
    String lugar_entrega = request.getParameter("lugar_entrega");
    String codigo_estudio_mercado = request.getParameter("codigo_estudio_mercado");        
    java.sql.Timestamp fecha_registro = new java.sql.Timestamp(fechaHoy);        
    String listRequisitosTemp = request.getParameter("listRequisitos");
    String listProveedoresTemp = request.getParameter("listProveedores");
    String listItemsTemp = request.getParameter("listItems");
    String listProveedoresCotiTemp;

    EstudioMercado bean = new EstudioMercado();
    bean.setAno_eje(ano_eje);
    bean.setTipo_bien(tipo_bien);
    bean.setNro_pedido(nro_pedido);
    bean.setNro_consolid(nro_consolid);
    bean.setNro_paac(nro_paac);
    bean.setNro_est_mdo(nro_est_mdo);               
    bean.setConcepto(concepto);
    bean.setGlosa_est_mdo(glosa_est_mdo);
    bean.setFecha_pedido(fecha_pedido);
    bean.setFecha_reg_vb(fecha_reg_vb);
    bean.setFecha_paac(fecha_paac);
    bean.setFecha_mdo(fecha_mdo);
    bean.setEstado_est_mdo(estado_est_mdo);
    bean.setPlazo(plazo);        
    bean.setUrl_documento(url_documento);
    bean.setUrl_justificacion(url_justificacion);
    bean.setLugar_entrega(lugar_entrega);
    bean.setCodigo_estudio_mercado(codigo_estudio_mercado);
    bean.setFecha_registro_estmdo(fecha_registro);
    */
    String SAVE_DIR = "DOCSX";
    pathFtp = obtenerPropiedad("pathFtp");
    String savePath = pathFtp + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;

    // creates the save directory if it does not exists
    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdir();
    }

    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

    /*for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        String fileName="";
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String s : items) {
            if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                fileName = s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
            }
        }
        // refines the fileName in case it is an absolute path
        fileName = new File(fileName).getName();
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
    }*/

    HashMap outHash = new HashMap();
    outHash.put("msg", "ok" + fileName); 
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").create();
    String arg = gson.toJson(outHash);
    response.getWriter().print(arg);



}
```

}

EL **ERROR** QUE ME SALE ES

Estado HTTP 500 - org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
type Informe de Excepci�n

mensaje org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

descripci�n El servidor encontr� un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepci�n

java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2807)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3073)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1095)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorRequestWrapper.getParameter(MonitorRequestWrapper.java:199)
    gob.grsm.estudiomercado.servlet.EstudioMercadoServlet.processRequest(EstudioMercadoServlet.java:64)
    gob.grsm.estudiomercado.servlet.EstudioMercadoServlet.doPost(EstudioMercadoServlet.java:541)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Comment: Mirá el error está del lado del servidor seguramente ya que el 500 indica éso, y justamente es algo que no dejaste,te recomendaría que subas el código correspondiente de back end correspondiente a este servicio.

Comment: al ultimo está el servlet.... un poco desordenado pero ahi ta :)